# onLongPress event with react-native-tvos not working on android tv controller

Tags: react-native, android-tv, react-native-tvos

i' developping an app for android tv using react native and the react-native-tvos package to handle tv gestures.

the onLongPress event on a touchable opacity does not work when testing on an android tv emulator.
i'm i missing something?

Comment: no point on touching tv. what you need to touch is the tv controller. which does not support long press. sends a single signal to tv to identify which button you press. maybe thats why?

Comment: Thanks a lot @SerkanEkşioğlu, i used useTVEventHandler to detect whether the press is a select or a long select and do the work accordingly.